# Download data from rpivotTable

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am working with RMarkdown. In my code I used rpivotTable. This table works fine but now I want to add buttons above the table for downloading data. This command work for me well with datatable and I want to implement it with rpivotTable.

I try to do this with the code below

```
rpivotTable(

             Indicator_1,

             aggregatorName = "Integer Sum",

             vals="Total",

             cols = "Participant",

             width="100%",

             height="400px",

             rendererName = "Table",

                 buttons=c('copy','csv','excel','pdf','print'),
)
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this ?

Comment: I think I can help, but do you want them to download the raw data, the pivot table, or something in between? Also, what type of output is your RMD? It might be a good idea to add your YAML to the question because different outputs and themes can change how RMD interprets the information. I doubt this will be an R native action—it will most likely require JS.